# AWS EventBridge - ScheduleExpression with cron

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, aws-event-bridge

I'm trying to achieve a cron task based event bridge rule and facing one issue. I'll get a timestamp in input and want to create a cron expression to run the rule hourly starting from the input timestamp.
For example if the input timestamp is **14:30** then the cron expression that my program builds looks something like this

```
"cron(30 14/1 * * * ? *)"
```

But while creating the eventbridge rule I'm getting the following error

```
AmazonServiceException thrown while handling: Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid. ValidationException
```

Can someone help me with this? What's wrong in this expression?

Comment: Shouldn't it be 30 14/1 * * * ..?

Answer (score 0):

From this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html):

> Cron expressions have six required fields, which are separated by
> white space.

So you have too many fields in your expression.  Try

```
"cron(30 14/1 * * ? *)"
```